# how to get AutoIncrement value to start with 1 each time table is created

Tags: android, sqlite

I have couple of tables which will have new data every time the user logs into the application. I have a column `KEY_ROWID` which is `autoIncrement`. I want it to always start with 1.
I tried truncating the table before new data is inserted. I get an error:

> "android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "TRUNCATE": syntax
>   error (code 1): , while compiling: TRUNCATE TABLE StaffListTable"

Sugestions much appreciated.

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_STAFFLIST = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_STAFFLIST + " (" 
                                                        + KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                                                        + KEY_STAFFID + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                                                        + KEY_STAFFNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL);";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its very simple, since you are truncating the table values I understand you don't have to secure them or take a back up. In such a case just dropping the table will do the trick.

In onUpdate() method, write

```
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+DATABASE_TABLE); //and call onCreate again
onCreate(db);
```

Let me know if you need anything else. Happy coding. :)

Comment: Hurray, great :). you can also upvote or accept the answer if it helped you. :)

Answer (score 0):

There's no `TRUNCATE` in sqlite. You can use `DROP` to delete tables if you really need to.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to effect a truncate (which SQLite doesn't have). You can either DROP and then CREATE as per other answers here.

Alternatively you can do a DELETE to empty the table and then remove the entry for the table from sqlite_sequence:

```
DELETE FROM sqlite_sequence
WHERE name = 'table_name'
```

sqlite_sequence holds the last used autoincrement value for tables with such columns. Removing the row for a given table will make the autoincrement key start at 1 again.

Comment: In the sqllite_sequence statement you gave. what does name stand for?
i tried it i got the error "android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: StaffListTable (code 1): , while compiling: DELETE FROM SQLITE_SEQUENCE WHERE name = StaffListTable"

Comment: The table sqlite_sequence has two columns: 'name' holds the table name and 'seq' holds the last used autoincrement integer. Since 'name' is a text column, you need to quote your table name in your statement: DELETE FROM SQLITE_SEQUENCE WHERE name = 'StaffListTable'

Comment: Is it the exact same message? Can you show the code that you are building the SQL statement string with?

Comment: i tried what @atul suggested and it worked for me.
thanks for your help. much appreciated

Comment: String comparison is case sensitive. The table name as stored in `sqlite_sequence` is probably "STAFFLISTTABLE" or "stafflisttable"